# How to use max in a where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In our database each client can have up to 3 phone numbers and each phone number is related with an ID_phone_number and an ID_type_phone and the id_person.

So I need to do a generic select where it returns the phone number that has the id_type_phone = '2' and has the higher id_phone_number related with this id_person.

This select needs to work for my entire database so I can't specify the id_person on it

I have:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT collun1.phone WHERE collun1.ID_type_phone = '2')
FROM collun1
WHERE id_person = 4
```

---

I want something like

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT collun1.phone WHERE collun1.ID_type_phone = '2' and max(id_phone_number)
FROM collun1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use SQL Server's Rank function with PARTITION and ORDER BY

Something like

```
Select * from (
    Select  RANK() OVER (
        PARTITION BY id_person 
        ORDER BY id_phone_number desc) AS phoneRank
        ,*
    from    collun1
    WHERE   collun1.ID_type_phone = '2') as tempSub
where phoneRank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax:

```
SELECT id_person, phone 
FROM collun1 
WHERE ID_type_phone = '2' AND id_phone_number = (SELECT MAX(id_phone_number) FROM collun1 c WHERE c.id_person = collun1.id_person)
```

Comment: This is very close to what I need.
Only that the select is giving me nulls for the others phone the person have. I neet it to not bring the nulls at all

Exemple adding id_person = 4 (this guy have 3 phone): 
ID_person  New_collun_from_select_given
4                  NULL
4                  NULL
4                  989361351

I need it to give only the '4                  989361351' as the other 2 lines with null never existed 

If you could help me with that too...
Thanks a lot for the the help already anyway!

Answer (score 0):

A `GROUP BY` would probably be faster (depending on your data):

```
SELECT id_person, MAX(ID_phone_number) 
FROM collun1 
WHERE ID_type_phone = '2' 
GROUP BY id_person
```

Answer (score 0):

So i got it by creating a temporary table based on the Hadi answer.

I did:`

```
CREATE TABLE ##Celphone (
Num_Phone varchar(14),
ID_Person numeric(8)); 

insert into ##Celphone (Num_Phone, ID_Person)
        SELECT Phone, ID_Person
        FROM COLLUN1 
        WHERE ID_Type_Phone = '2' AND ID_Phone = (SELECT MAX(ID_Phone) FROM COLLUN1 C WHERE C.ID_Person = COLLUN1.ID_Person)

SELECT DISTINCT
       ##Celphone.Num_Phone,
       ID_Person
```